# Python/SQLAlchemcy "or" functionality

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-sqlalchemy

I can't seem to find out why "or" is behaving the way it is. I'm using SQLAlchemy and `WTForms.ext.sqlalchemy.QuerySelectField` and `QuerySelectField` can have `query_factory` set, but if it's missing it should be falling back to the fields `query` method:

e.g.

```
class Form1(Form):
    fielda = QuerySelectField('Field A')
```

You can also set the `query_factory` argument like so:

```
class Form1(Form):
    fielda = QuerySelectField('Field A', query_factory=somefunction)
```

Then somewhere else you use the form like so:

```
form = Form1(request.form)
form.fielda.query = MyObjects.query.all()
```

What I'm seeing is that, if `MyObjects.query.all()` returns an empty list, I get a `NoneType not callable` exception on this line in the QuerySelectField _get_object_list() method:

```
query = self.query or self.query_factory()
```

Basically, no matter what the value of `self.query`, the `or` is still calling `self.query_factory()` even if it is assigned to `None`.

So, my question is, is this expected behaviour of `or`? It appears that it evaluates both and *then* it decides if it needs to use the second value if the first is `None`. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you sure that it's the `or` that's calling `self.query_factory()` here? Are you sure that there is not something else that's calling `self.query_factory()`?

Answer (score 1):

`or` short-circuits. This means that

```
query = self.query or self.query_factory()
```

is evaluated as follows:

1. Check if `self.query` evaluates to `False`. If not, then the object referenced by `self.query` is bound to `query`. `self.query_factory()` *is not called* in this situation.
2. If it *is* a `False`y value (including `None`), then `self.query_factory()` is called and its result bound to `query`.

Comment: I'm not seeing this in my tests. When I run it, no matter the value of self.query (None or a positive value), self.query_factory() is always being evaluated.

Comment: There must be something else that's calling that method, then. Try `def test(): print "Bzzt!"` and then do `1 or test()` vs. `0 or test()` or `None or test()`.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct None is false in a Boolean context. If self.query is None then the value is determined by self.query_factory()

[Python docs on what is true and false](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#booleans)

Answer (score 0):

You can succinctly state the behavior of `or` as:

> if the left object is True-like, it returns the left object, otherwise it returns the right object.

---

In this case, left object is false-like (`None`), so it needs to call the function in order to get the right object to return.

Comment: Actually, if the object to the left it false, it returns the object to the right. E.g.: `0 or ''` returns `''` and `0 or 'a'` returns `'a'`.